# Azure devops previous build error - Preparing zip package' operation conflicts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have a couple of env in Azure dev ops, one env azure function fails with the following error

> 2024-02-09T14:55:16.5402362Z ##[error]Assertion failed: Deployment
> wasn't successful: The 'Preparing zip package' operation conflicts
> with the pending 'Preparing zip package' operation started at
> 2024-02-09T14:53:19.8719001Z.  Please retry operation later.

There were no previous operations that were unsuccessful, tried with a different build agent with no success, and deleted the function app but I still getting the same error, any other way I can get past or clear the old deployment leftover,
only one env getting an error, all others successful

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [**Github issue**](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/3042) and this [**comment**](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/3042#issuecomment-665659432) for the resolution of your error. Other customers are able to resolve this issue by Upgrading their Web app to higher SKU, Example- Basic to Standard to Premium, ***You can upgrade your Function App to Premium plan and select higher SKU***:-

[image]

Also, Check for the pending deployments on the same repository. Also, Try changing the Function App OS from Linux to Windows or vice versa and try the deployment again.

You can cancel any on-going deployments in your Azure DevOps Pipelines tab and run the latest one:-

[image]

My **Function App** Deployment via **`Azure DevOps build pipeline`**:-

**YAML pipeline:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- master

variables:
  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxab873'

  
  functionAppName: 'siliconfunc743'

  
  vmImageName: 'windows-2019'

  
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: |
          $(workingDirectory)/*.csproj
        arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionApp
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

[image]

[image]